# cannot import function name

Tags: python, python-dateutil

All my files are in a same directory

I'm fresh in python and I'm trying to code functions in a Preprocessing file like this:

```
#Preprocessing file
from dateutil import parser
def dropOutcomeSubtype(DataFrame):
    DataFrame.drop('OutcomeSubtype',axis=1,inplace='True')

def convertTimestampToTime(Serie):
    for i in range(0,len(Serie)):
        parser.parse(Serie[i]).time()
```

And then I'm trying to use it in a Exporting file like this:

```
#Import external librairies 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

#import our librairy
from Preprocessing import convertTimestampToTime, dropOutcomeSubtype

#Reading
Datas = pd.read_csv("../Csv/train.csv", sep=",", na_values=['NaN'])

dropOutcomeSubtype(Datas)
convertTimestampToTime(Datas.DateTime)
```

And when i try to run the code in my OSX shell with this config:
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)| IPython 5.1.0

I have get this error: cannot import name 'convertTimestampToTime'

and if change my import statement like this:

```
from Preprocessing import *
```

I get this error: name 'convertTimestampToTime' is not defined

Can you explain me why please ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: it searchs `Preprocessing.py` in "current working directory" - and it can be different than folder with script. If it can't find in CWD (current working directory) then it try to import installed modules - try `import Preprocessing` and `print(Preprocessing.__file__)` to see what file was imported.

Comment: @furas And so ? I can't get your point. What do you advice me to do ?

Comment: first try `import Preprocessing` and `print(Preprocessing.__file__)` to see what file was imported.

Comment: @furas it gives me this : /Users/SIMON/Desktop/Tx/Script/Preprocessing.py

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can add mod path to sys.path. if both in same dir add this code at first of main code

```
import os
import sys
here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(here)
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. 

Thank you for the answer

Comment: maybe you have to use `insert(0, here)` instead of `append(here)`  to put this folder before other folders which also can have file `Preprocessing.py`