# cannot import name 'function' from 'file' on collab

Tags: python, import, google-colaboratory

I have a helper_functions.py file that I want to use some functions from, but nothing seems to work.

`from helper_functions import plot_decision_boundary`

*ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_decision_boundary' from 'helper_functions' (/content/helper_functions.py)*

`from helper_functions import *`

runs, but when I call any function I get

*name 'plot_decision_boundary' is not defined*

I tried the solutions to the two most similar questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42037936/cannot-import-function-name) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58405054/i-cannot-import-function-name-from-another-file), but nothing seems to work.

I am working on collab and have manually uploaded the file.

!ls lists the file

Comment: Do you have an empty `__init__.py` on the same level as helper_functions.py?

Answer (score 0):

Then I leave you some examples of different ways to import a module.

Your file:

```
  # module.py
      def fun1(n):
          return n+1
```

1-> import:

```
import module
module.fun1(1000) #1001
```

2-> from:

```
from module import fun1
fun1(1000) #1001
```

3-> import *:

```
from module import *
fun1(1000) #1001
```

4-> import as:

```
import module as lib
lib.fun1(1000) #1001
```

Make sure that the file you want to import is in the same folder, if it is not in the same folder, indicate the name in the "import" if the folder is in the same root.

```
from .MyFolder import module
```

References:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Importing_Modules

Answer (score 0):

I just had exactly the same problem. Solution is to Restart Colab Session.

Runtime > Restart Session (Ctrl + M)